# SpringBoot with multiple DB configuration exception

Tags: spring-boot

I have configured SpringBoot with 2 MySQL DB on the same application. 
The two DB from different packages.

1. `com.appscook.keycloak.usermanagement.sdk.entity`
2. `com.appscook.library.domain`

**properties file**

```
#SDK DB CONFIG
keycloaksdk.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
keycloaksdk.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/organization?autoReconnect=true
keycloaksdk.datasource.username=root
keycloaksdk.datasource.password=password

#LIBRARY DB CONFIG
library.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
library.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.188:3306/library_keycloak?autoReconnect=true
library.datasource.username = jijesh
library.datasource.password = jijesh


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
# Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.max-active=50
# Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**DB1 config**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.appscook.library.service")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "libraryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "libraryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.appscook.library.repository")
public class LibraryDBConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "library.datasource")
    public DataSource hrmsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean libraryEntityManagerFactory(
            final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(hrmsDataSource())
                .packages("com.appscook.library.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("libraryPersistenceUnit").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager hrmsTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("libraryEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

**Db2 config**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.appscook.keycloak.usermanagement.sdk.services")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "keycloakEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "keycloakTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.appscook.keycloak.usermanagement.sdk.repository")
public class KeycloakSDKDBConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloaksdk.datasource")
    public DataSource keycloakDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean keycloakEntityManagerFactory(
            final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(keycloakDataSource())
                .packages("com.appscook.keycloak.usermanagement.sdk.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("keycloakPersistenceUnit").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager keycloakTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("keycloakEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

When i run app the console showing NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: libraryEntityManagerFactory,keycloakEntityManagerFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble with `openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` bean, set
`spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in your application properties file. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), this bean binds the default EntityManager (which it obtains from the default EntityManagerFactory) to the request thread, and for some reason this is on by default.

You can also consider making one of the factories primary:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean libraryEntityManagerFactory(
        final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.dataSource(hrmsDataSource())
            .packages("com.appscook.library.domain")
            .persistenceUnit("libraryPersistenceUnit").build();
}
```